# Why is Hasura erring on startup with "following root fields are duplicated" in beta8?

Tags: graphql, hasura

This question is for a Hasura application running against a Postgres database.  When running beta6, everything is working.  However, after updating to beta8, Hasura does not start.

Here is the last log message when starting with beta6:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-23T19:07:55.521+0000",
    "level": "info",
    "type": "startup",
    "detail": {
        "kind": "server",
        "info": {
            "time_taken": 0.486567746,
            "message": "starting API server"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the last log message starting with beta8:

```
{
    "path": "$.args[0].args",
    "error": "following root fields are duplicated: ******",
    "code": "unexpected"
}
```

We are carrying on with beta6 for now, if anyone has an open communications channel with Hasura, it might be good to let them know they introduced a breaking change with their latest release.  It would be good to get on the upgrade pathway again, hopefully we are not stuck on beta6 for whatever reason.

Comment: Hello! Someone was kind enough to cross-post your Stack Overflow question to [our issue tracker](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3220), and indeed, this update was not intended to be breaking! If you could share some details with us about your schema (ideally over on GitHub), we can help diagnose what the issue is.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks @AlexisKing!  I am providing feedback over there, happy to do what I can to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, this was due to a naming convention Hasura uses, to add `_aggregate` to the table name when defining resolvers for select statements against a table.  We also happen to use `_aggregate` for our own table naming convention, used when one table rolls up, or aggregates, the values in another table.

This caused the root naming collision in the composed graph.

Hasura was able to provide a manual workaround, documented in the GitHub issue:

https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3220